# Insert arrow buttons

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage and a slider inside a picture. Right now the slider moves left and right on its own I want to insert clickable arrow keys that will navigate the user left and right.

```
<body>
<div id="slider">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="slide">
      <h3>Slide 1</h3>
      <p>#</p>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <h3>Slide 2</h3>
      <p>#</p>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <h3>Slide 3</h3>
      <p>#</p>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <h3>Slide 4</h3>
      <p>#</p>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <h3>Slide 5</h3>
      <p>#</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

and this is the CSS

```
#slider,  #slider .slide{
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
}
#slider {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
#slider .container {
  position: relative;
  width: 9000px; /* Assign an insanely large width */
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  animation: slide-animation 25s infinite;
}
#slider .slide {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

@keyframes slide-animation {
  0% { 
    opacity: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
  11% {
    opacity: 1;
    right: 0; 
  }
  22% { right: 100%; }
  33% { right: 100%; }
  44% { right: 200%; }
  55% { right: 200%; }
  66% { right: 300%; }
  77% { right: 300%; }
  88% {
    opacity: 1;
    right: 400%; 
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    right: 400%;
  }
}
```

Any help would be largely appreciated what code to use for arrow keys?
Where to insert div of arrow keys?
How to make the left and right keys work?
Even if you don't know the full answer any type of help is good.

Answer (score 0):

You solely need to download some icons - therefore I recommend [Feather](https://feathericons.com/) icons - insert them as images and make them clickable for example by using JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I don't use JS

Comment: Unfortunately there‘s now way around JS.